# Scipy - statistical tests between two groups

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

I have two samples from the population of neurons in the brain, each sample consisting of a thousand neuron instances, of categories:

1. cerebellum
2. cortex

Now I'm extracting multiple metrics for each sample using complex network analysis, for example, neuron degree of connectivity `k`, a discreet number n = 0, 1, ...., n, or clustering coefficient `C`, a continous value between 0.00000 and 1.00000.

`df.sample(3)` (where web is category) in my pandas dataframes:

cortex:

```
         web    k   clustering_coeff
3080    cortex  6.0         0.733333        
2951    cortex  11.0        0.428571    
1435    cortex  5.0         0.563571    

...
```

cerebellum

```
815 cerebellum  10.0        0.533333    
850 cerebellum  9.0         0.416667    
1213 cerebellum 7.0         0.454545
...
```

---

How can I use `scipy` `stats` methods to I compare both metrics in order to know if theres a statistically significant difference between the two gropus?

Assuming a distribution close to Gaussian, but skewed to the right, I'm not sure what is the best approach. Parametric, Non-Parametric, T-test and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is rather a question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: i think I’m being explicit about scipy as a tool for my goal

Comment: I understand your question as "Which test should I use"? You can write a script to use a t-test for data without normal distribution. scipy will not check the validity of your approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the "k" metric:

```
stats.mannwhitneyu(df.loc[df.web=="cortex", "k"], df.loc[df.web=="cerebellum", "k"])
```

for the "clustering_coeff" metric:

```
stats.mannwhitneyu(df.loc[df.web=="cortex", "clustering_coeff"], df.loc[df.web=="cerebellum", "clustering_coeff"])
```

In general use a non-parametric test if you don't know anything about the distribution in exam.

Comment: Thank you. And what is the test if I do know something about the distribution, in this case? Could you expand your answer for that scenario as well?

Comment: @8-BitBorges it depends. In this case you are comparing two groups with independent samples, so you need a mann-whitney test. But there are lot of non-parametric tests for other application (example correlation test).

Comment: @8-BitBorges otherwise if in this case you know that your variables follow a gaussian distribution you can apply a t-test (`stats.ttest_ind`)